# Attaching external disk on kubernetes pod in azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes

I want to attach an external disk to kubernetes pod in azure environment. According to documentation here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/release-1.2/examples/azure_file it uses azure file system.

What if I want to use the OS disks (external disks) like we have in gcloud environment ?

Comment: Based on the discussion with azure solution architect, you can only use azureFile as column driver at this point. azureVhd is in progress https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/23259.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure volumes piece was merged: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/examples/azure_file/README.md